# WordPress: Display Google Ads to guest users only

Tags: wordpress, ads

I have a WordPress website and a registration system in it. Lets say I have the following Google Ad example:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1234567890123456" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

How can I display the Ad only to guest users? I've been stuck with this for days. Is there a plugin? or can I edit the user roles somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<?php if( false === is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1234567890123456" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

<?php } // endif ?>
```